# ISessionFactory recreates after app pool recycles

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, iis, application-pool

My shared hosting provider set up IIS recycle app pool every 3 minutes for idle.
So my session factory often recreates (at application startup). As I have about 70-100 entities it takes about 2-5 seconds to construct factory. So cold start of my application is rather long. I haven't access to IIS setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to stop your site from being idle in the first place? I use [uptime robot](http://www.uptimerobot.com/) that is **FREE** and pings your site every 5 minutes. The benefit of this service is that it only requests the headers of the page you set up as a monitor and therefore does not affect logging such as Google Analytics.

However said you will need to test this to see when your app does indeed recycle to see if uptime robot works with your shared hosting provider. The best way is to log every time the session factory is re-built.

Comment: thanks for service. Can I setup period. For example to 2:30 ?

Comment: No but wondering why you want this? This service pings you site EVERY 5 mins and sends an alert if it is down.

Comment: My idle timeout is 3 minute, so i need hit it every 3 minute

Comment: Oh I see I thought you meant 2:30 in the day not 2.5 minute intervals.  3 minutes is a **VERY** low idle timeout so your hosting provider is not a good one... I suspect uptime robot will not help you here as it is 5 minute intervals, and I don't think you want to write your own. Personally I think NHibernate and your hosting provider are not a good match for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in a full trust environment (doubtful, but provider may be willing to work with you on this), you can try serializing your configuration so it doesn't need to be rebuilt each time.  Merging all your entity mappings into a single XML doc can help also (just do this as build step so its not a nightmare to work with mappings).

More info here: http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/03/13/an-improvement-on-sessionfactory-initialization.html

Answer (score 2):

You can offset a lot of the cost of setting up your factory by generating your proxies at build-time instead of runtime. [This article](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/pre-generate-lazy-loading-proxies.aspx) explains the steps how.

Being realistic, the simplest change is to ask that the app-pool isn't recycled so frequently (since this is an expensive operation for your application). I'm sure they've set the timeout very low as a "performance" setting, but really this is generating work and slowing things down.

You might not have access to the IIS settings directly, but this shouldn't stop you from contacting your supplier's technical support and getting it resolved.

Comment: Does this work in an medium trust environment? Also is it 3.2 compatible? Just curious that's all...

Comment: IIRC, pre-generating proxies is *required* if you want to use lazy loading in a medium trust environment.  So it should work :)

Comment: It wants 2.0 from me:(. And my NHIb is 3.2

Answer (score 1):

not much you can do. app pool recycle shuts down your app...

I guess you could try to fool the recycler by having the application do something every 2:45.